# Outputting SQLite version from an app using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

In an application using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`, is it possible to output which version of SQLite is being used? If not, what could be some workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var version = new SqliteConnection().ServerVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

By running `SELECT sqlite_version()`:

```
private static string GetSqliteVersion(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT sqlite_version();";
        return (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```